# MatLab: put my asnwer into matrix format 21x1

Tags: matlab

```
for t = 0:20
    y1 = 2*t*x + 2*b1 + b2
end
```

How do I put the answer into matrix form. I should have four 21x1 matrices. 
I have tried this

```
for t = 0:20
    y1 = [2*t*x + 2*b1 + b2]
end
```

But it keep giving me

```
y1 =

    4.5000


y2 =

    5.1227


y3 =

   -0.3312


y4 =

   -4.4375


y1 =

    6.5000


y2 =

    7.1012


y3 =

    2.9776


y4 =

   -3.2167


y1 =

    8.5000


y2 =

    8.3758


y3 =

    4.2008


y4 =

   -0.5430


y1 =

   10.5000


y2 =

   10.6748


y3 =

    5.7916


y4 =

    2.3107


y1 =

   12.5000


y2 =

   12.7804


y3 =

    7.8259


y4 =

    3.6318


y1 =

   14.5000


y2 =

   15.3632


y3 =

   11.0662


y4 =

    5.8714


y1 =

   16.5000


y2 =

   16.4324


y3 =

   12.0206


y4 =

    7.6385
........
```

Comment: Your code does not have `y2, y3` or `y4` shown anywhere.  How are you getting those variables appearing in your code?

Comment: It's just for example. I do have the rest of the equation. But I just need to know how to put answer into matrix format.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, as @rayryeng said. Please provide an example that exactly reproduces the problem

Comment: @LuisMendo - #mentalist

Comment: @rayryeng Indeed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this without `for` loops. For the `y1` case, assuming `x`, `b1`, `b2` are constants:

```
t = 0:20;
y1 = 2*t*x + 2*b1 + b2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = 0:20
y1 = nan(size(t));
for ii = 1:length(t)
    y1(ii) = 2*t(ii)*x + 2*b1 + b2;
end
```

Try this instead. You need to put the answer in a different location every loop iteration. Right now you overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your goal to have four "21 x 1" matrices, simply do what eigenchris said and do this outside of loop:

```
t = 0:20;
y1 = 2*t*x + 2*b1 + b2;
y2 = ...;
y3 = ...;
y4 = ...;
```

If you want to do this inside of a loop, either **pre-allocate** the space for `y1, y2, y3, y4` then **index** inside the loop, or **append** the results each time.  Your `for` loop keeps overwriting `y1, y2, y3, y4` at each iteration in the loop and is not saving the results

### Method #1

```
t = 0:20;
y1 = zeros(numel(t), 1);
y2 = y1; y3 = y1; y4 = y1;
for idx = 1 : numel(t)
    y1(idx) = 2*t(idx)*x + 2*b1 + b2;
    y2(idx) = ...;
    y3(idx) = ...;
    y4(idx) = ...;
end
```

Make sure you index `t` by `t(idx)` for each equation after `y1`.

### Method #2

```
y1 = []; y2 = []; y3 = []; y4 = [];
for t = 0 : 20
    y1 = [y1; 2*t*x + 2*b1 + b2];
    y2 = [y2; ...];
    y3 = [y3; ...];
    y4 = [y4; ...];
end
```